# heroku client stopped working

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

It was working just fine this morning but suddenly it giving me such error. I tried to uninstall and install it but no luck. Would appreciate if anyone can help me in it.

```
c:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- multi_json (LoadError)
from c:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from C:/Users/Somenath/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Users/Somenath/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/cli.rb:1:in `load'
from C:/Users/Somenath/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/cli.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from c:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from c:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from c:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/bin/heroku:27:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Upgrade to version 3.6.0 of the Heroku Toolbelt.

https://status.heroku.com/incidents/598

Comment: Solved the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue. The error that's occurring is that it's trying to load the "multi_json" gem, but it wasn't on my machine. I doubt it's on your machines either.

What I think happened is that Heroku updated their client and are now using this gem in their code, but they forgot to add it as a dependency so it would be automatically pulled down when updating? That's just my guess.

Regardless, installing the multi_json gem fixed it for me:

```
gem install multi_json
```