# heroku cli deprecated after installing the latest version on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: heroku-cli

I get the following error:

▸    heroku-cli: This CLI is deprecated. Please reinstall from https://cli.heroku.com

I have tried both:

`curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install.sh | sudo sh`

and

`sudo snap install heroku --classic`

This gives the following error:
error: cannot perform the following tasks:

`- Run configure hook of "heroku" snap if present (run hook "configure": /usr/local/bin/heroku: line 18: cd: HOME not set)`

as recommended here

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#download-and-install

It was working fine until yesterday.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44333834/heroku-cli-suddenly-broken This worked!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Heroku CLI suddenly broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44333834/heroku-cli-suddenly-broken)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too, and I followed this [doc](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) , and the issue was fixed by running this command:

> curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install.sh | sh